# Getting Policy sync failed with status code 503 while integrating mip sdk on Android

Tags: android, azure-information-protection, microsoft-information-protection, mip-sdk

I am working on integrating mip sdk version 1.6 as per [latest release document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/version-release-history#version-16103) on Android. I am able to get access token but when provided to initialize policy engine, it throws below error.

**Failed API call: profile_add_engine_async Failed with: [NetworkError: 'Policy sync failed, NetworkError.Category=Throttled, HttpRequest.SanitizedUrl=https://dataservice.protection.outlook.com/PsorWebService/v1/ClientSyncFile/MipPolicies, HttpRequest.Id={EC1D0F76-3A38-4F8A-AAC6-TB9059W1B9AM}, HttpResponse.StatusCode=503, CorrelationId=a9381643-2n1r-4q66-933j-77848ca3e15a, CorrelationId.Description=PolicyProfile']**

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Why are you supporting all the way back to 1.6? Theres no telling how many errors you will run into supporting such an old version

Comment: @Jaime this is the latest version available as per official document here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/information-protection/develop/version-release-history#version-16103

Comment: Ah i misread, thought it was the Android SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try again and it should work :) The network error indicated you were throttled for some reason. It should be only temporary.

Comment: Hi @Tom , thank you for checking. It turned out a different issue as mentioned in [above post ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142005/5169895) . Error code looks like a default one.

Answer (score 0):

It started working after migrating AIP labels to unified labels as mentioned in [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/information-protection/configure-policy-migrate-labels). The returned error code does not provide any information about failure of this type.

I am still trying to understand how the step is mandatory. As per the description in link, AIP should be supported till 03/31/2021 .